# Perforce: how to view the entire history of a single file

Tags: perforce

The contents of a prior submission are missing from the latest sync. It may have been lost due an intermediate bad submit. I would like to go through the entire history to recover it.

I tried:

```
p4 filelog <file name>
```

but it lists only the changelist numbers with some metadata. I looked through the options and -l provides the most info but is still limited to changelist description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

`p4 annotate -a <file name>`

Look for the missing contents; you'll see what revision they were added in and the last revision that they were present in (so the revision after that will indicate when they were removed and by whom).

The "Time-Lapse View" tool in P4V is a graphical version of `p4 annotate` that is easier to use than the CLI version IMO.

If you literally just want to see the full contents of each revision all at once, that's:

`p4 print -a <file name>`

Comment: Time-Lapse View is awesome!